# jQuery select and deselect textbox text

Tags: jquery

I want functionality like on the focus event of text box i want to select the text of text box and on click of textbox i want to check if text in the textbox is selected then deselect it other wise select.

for this i have added code like:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
  $(this).select();
});
```

what code i should add on click event so that it can fulfill the requirment

Thanks & Regards

Munish

Comment: Are you sure you want this? This would mean, that whenever a user clicks to set the cursor at a certain position, the whole text is selected or deselected, and therefore the user cannot use mouse click to position the cursor. This is unexpected behaviour compared to "normal" text boxes, so think about it twice!

Comment: Dont understand why you would want to do this? When a user clicks again in a text box he/she has already got focus so .select() is not run again and then the text is unselected. If the user clicks elsewhere on the page the text is de-selected anyway so if they click in the box again its going to select all the text...

Comment: You can use the [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event.

Comment: You can use focus out property for this [focus out](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the user the ability to overwrite what's in there already, you could just set it blank instead:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
  $(this).val('').removeClass('default-value');
});

$('input').blur(function(){
  if ($(this).val()=='')
    $(this).val('default value').addClass('default-value');
});
```

The `addClass`/`removeClass` bits aren't required... they're just there so that you can make the default value show up as grey or italics or something if you wish. To me, that looks quite professional.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery dox here on the [`.select()` method](http://api.jquery.com/select/) say the following:

> The method for retrieving the current selected text differs from one browser to another. A number of jQuery plug-ins offer cross-platform solutions.

So on the face of it it looks like you'll have to go down the plugin route to determine whether text is selected or not inside your input control.

I would also echo Felix's caveat that what you are doing does interfere with user expectations of how an input-text element will behave when clicked and that you should think carefully about whether your requirements really indicate this is the way to go.